# Alpine Linux ISO put on USB Harddisk with rufus just boots through to installed OS

Tags: linux, boot, alpine-linux, rufus

I am experimenting with replacing a USB-pen with a USB-harddisk as the boot media when installing Alpine Linux to get faster response time while developing an automated installer for older legacy PCs running a custom solution.  The ISO was written to the USB-harddisk with Rufus under Windows 10 with a MBR layout in ISO-mode.

The USB-harddisk is 1 TB (as a 3TB disk gave messages saying it was too big) and it is found when entering the "Boot from other media" option in the BIOS, but when selected it almost immediately goes to boot the current installation on the harddisk in the machine without starting the installer on the USB-harddisk.  The same procedure works as expected with an USB-key.

What is going on here and can it be fixed?

Comment: If you press F12 during the POST, do you get to the boot device menu?

Comment: @Peregrino69 I get to the boot device menu (using F11) and I can choose the USB-harddisk.  Then after about 1 second the OS on the internal harddisk starts to boot.

Comment: I trust you've tried both UEFI and Legacy settings in BIOS? And Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: These are very old machines, and do not have UEFI.  Legacy settings are set (the harddisk shows up in the boot menu ).

Comment: Yap, I was just thinking maybe something went wrong creating the installer with an UEFI system... I'm actually doing something similar - I've got a 1TB HDD partitioned 1GB for Clonezilla, bootable, and rest for imaging. That works. Is your HDD a single partition? Admittedly I'm grasping straws, but don't see many others pitching in so...

Comment: If clonezilla works with alpine I am fine with trying that instead.  Thanks for the pointer.